# How to calculate a parent inverse matrix?

Tags: python, parent, matrix

Say I want to parent the default Cube to the camera from python without using an operator.

First part is easy:

```
Cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
Camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']

Cube.parent = Camera
```

Now I want the cube to remain in place like it would if I used the operator. I assume I have to perform an operation on one of the camera's matrices and assign the result to the cube's `matrix_parent_inverse`, but what operation would it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wow, that was embarrassingly easy.

```
Cube.matrix_parent_inverse = Cam.matrix_local.inverted
```

Comment: So easy that you forgot the parentheses... inverted is a function!
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.inverted
So the conversion is: Cube.matrix_parent_inverse = Cam.matrix_local.inverted()